# switch between servers dynamically when network changes in cordova app using meteor

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I developed a meteor app.After installing it on mobile using local server ,I want to change server address from local to cloud to which my app should switch and run on that server.To do so,after referring some documents I found server picker package and installed it in my project, then added some part of code on client side of app.The code is as follows:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
 window.localStorage.setItem('url',"https://dcpldev.eu.meteorapp.com");
 var rootUrl= window.localStorage.getItem('url');
   if(rootUrl){
       console.log("mynetwork", __meteor_runtime_config__);
      __meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = __meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL =  rootUrl;
   if(Meteor && Meteor.absoluteUrl &&  typeof Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions == "object"){
        Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = rootUrl;
        console.log("mynetwork1324");
   }  
 }

  });
} 
 });
```

But, my server is switching to cloud server address,but I am losing login State.Please help me.

Comment: That is to be expected, as (1) the Cordova app is simply a wrapped web app with some extra APIs, and the session data should not be available across domains so it is not even sent to the cloud server, and (2) the server in the cloud should have no knowledge of the session created by your local server, so even if it were sent, the cloud would reject it (unless you cloned the DB with that session to the cloud).

Comment: how to clone the DB to the cloud?Can you please help me out?

Comment: There is very little use in cloning the local database to the cloud for copying session information. If you think that you need to do something like that, you are probably doing something wrong. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? Why would you need to create a session with the local server in the first place?